# PHPUnit Selenium-2 Test Case BadMethodCallException

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, php, phpunit

I have installed **selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar**, **phpUnit**, **selenium extension for phpUnit**.

This test runs ok:

```
$this->url('/');
$this->assertEquals('my title',$this->title());
```

But when I try to use `$this->byClassName('sideNav');`

I get

> `Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with the message 'The command http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/b527030f-a368-4845-b50c-2889910da917 is not recognized by the server.`

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run selenium server before you execute your test cases.

**Try following steps:**

1. Open Terminal / CMD.
2. Navigate to directory where your `selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar` is stored.

**E.g:** `cd /User/Documents/Selenium`

3. Execute following command to run the server

   `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar`

This will start selenium server.

**Note:** You will require JRE to be installed to run jar files in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should work:

```
$this->element($this->using('css selector')->value('*[class="sideNav"]'));
```

instead of

```
$this->byClassName('sideNav');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the tests of the project of [how to use this method](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php#L215):

```
public function testElementsKnowTheirTagName()
{
    $this->url('html/test_element_selection.html');
    $element = $this->byClassName('theDivClass');
    $this->assertEquals('div', $element->name());
}
```